Proof of section is smooth iff component functions are smooth
I'm trying to understand the proof of this lemma in "An introduction to manifolds" 2ed by Loring W.Tu. (p. 138)
Lemma 12.11 
Let $\phi:E|_U \longrightarrow U \times \mathbb{R}^r$ be a trivialization over an open set $U$ of a $C^\infty$ vector bundle $E \rightarrow M$ and $t_1, t_2, ..., t_r$ the $C^\infty$ frame over $U$ of the trivialization. Then a section $s=\sum b^{i}t_i$ is $C^\infty$ if and only if its coefficients $b^i$ relative to the frame $t_1, t_2, ..., t_r$ are $C^\infty$.
The proof in this book is,
Suppose the section $s=\sum b^{i}t_i$ is $C^\infty$ of $E$ over $U$ is $C^\infty$. Then $\phi \circ s$ is $C^\infty$. Note that $(\phi \circ s)(p)=\sum b^{i}(p) (\phi \circ t_{i})(p)=\sum b^{i}(p)(p,e_i)=(p,\sum b^i(p)e_i)$. Thus $b^i$ are simply the fiber coordinates of s(p) relative to the trivialization $\phi$. Since $\phi \circ s$ is $C^\infty$, all the $b^{i}$ are $C^\infty$.
The definition of fiber coordinates (in this book) is,
Let $\pi: E \rightarrow M$ be a smooth vector bundle and suppose $(U,\psi)=(U,x^1,x^2,...,x^n)$ is a chart on $M$. And let $\phi$ be a trivialization over $U$. Then $(\psi \times Id_{\mathbb{R}^n}) \circ \phi=(x^1,x^2,...x^n, c^1,..., c^r): E|_U \rightarrow \psi(U) \times \mathbb{R}^r \subset \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^r$ is a diffeomorphism from $E|_U$ onto its image. $x^1,...x^n$ are called the base coordinates, and $c^1,...,c^r$ are called the fiber coordinates.
But in this proof, do we have a coordinate function, say, $\psi$ defined on $U$? If it is the case, then I think the proof goes well as the codomain of $\phi \circ s$ is Euclidean space so we can use the component criterion on manifolds (e.g. Proposition 6.13 in this book). Or can we always assume that such a function exists? If not, how we can proceed?
(I also have read "Introduction to Smooth manifolds" by John M.Lee. This content was proposition 10.22 in p.260. But the proof ended without any further explanation. I guess some propositions or lemma about this have appeared in previous pages. But I cannot have found yet (due to the length of this book..?). If you know, then let me know.)

Yes, you certainly can assume that $U$ is contained in a coordinate chart on $M$.

@TedShifrin Thank you for comment. Could you explain more..? What I have thought was that for each point in $U \times \mathbb{R}^r$, choose a chart $(V, \psi)$ where $V \subset U$ and then use $(\psi \times Id_{\mathbb{R}^r}) \circ (\phi \circ s)$. As differentiability is a local property, I thought it suffices to choose a local chart for each point in $U$ even though we cannot assume a chart whose domain contains the whole $U$.

Yes, that's basically right. You're interested in proving a local result, so you can cover $M$ with charts over which the bundle is trivial (just restrict to intersections of charts and open sets over which the bundle is trivial). Of course, you cannot assume the original $U$ necessarily works — for example, you could have a trivial bundle and $U$ would then likely be all of $M$.

@TedShifrin Thanks for your answer. I can have confidence with my thought!
